# How does interp2(X,Y,image,XI,YI) knows to rotate the image when XI and YI is a rotated coordinate system of X and Y? and why not use imrotate?

Tags: matlab

In radon.m the projections in the various angles are done by rotating the original image using interp2(x1,y1,padImg,x,y) where x1 and y1 are gotten using meshgrid of n points between -1 and 1 (where n is the number of the rows of the zero padded image) and x and y are gotten from x1, and y1 by multiplying the vector (x1, y1) with a rotation matrix. I don't get the idea of this manipulation of interp2. How does interp2 knows that the image itself should be rotated? Can someone explain this to me please?  and also- why not use imrotate?

Comment: Just use the rotated `x` and `y` points as the points you want to interpolate with and `x1,y1` as the seed points (first two parameters of `interp2`).  The rotation should be visible.  BTW, Daniel is correct.  `interp2` doesn't know anything about your data.  You simply put in points you want to interpolate on.  BTW, yes use `imrotate` whenever possible.  It's easier.

Answer (score 1):

Interp2 does not know anything about rotation, it just interpolates at the points you put in. Plot x and y as 2d points, you will see that the rotation is already in there.